# Run admininstrator cmd with a VB Script

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I need to create a VB Script for Windows 7 computers that open a CMD with admin privileges, but i need to put the admin password too, and copy a file to the "Program Files" folder using this CMD window. The ideia is this:

```
      Set CmdShell=Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
      CmdShell.Run "runas /user:Domain\administrator ""cmd"""
      Wscript.Sleep 100
      CmdShell.SendKeys "Password~"
```

and then use the command below

```
      copy C:\teste\teste1.txt copy "C:\Program Files\QAD\teste4.txt"
```

How i run this command in a Admin CMD with password?

I don´t know if is clear for you, but if u need more information let me know.

Comment: It should be obvious that putting an administrative password in a script in plain text is a bad idea (this is why the runas program requires you to type a password, which you're trying to "hack" around by using SendKeys). Also, you can't bypass the UAC prompt. You need to tell what your purpose/goal is, not the intended solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would run the cmd as admin on a server and connect to remote machine by mapping their c drive by admin share (c$) thus you don't have to send password. Too you could use psexec if you need further action on the remote machine locally.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - you should answer him, not me. while because of this i wanted to show him a better way.

Comment: Sorry, clicked on the wrong comment box. I deleted and reposted under the question.